# How can my server know which client to respond to after a separate domain redirect?

Tags: javascript, java, http, server

For example,

I go to a webpage (webpage W), and now I am the client.

Server A is the server associated with the webpage, that I coded and have control over (coded in Java)

Server B is a server on a completely different domain, and I do not have control over it. It is running its own webpage.

Client sends Javascript AJAX request to server A, and server A responds with an OK. The code continues, and then the code redirects the page to server B's webpage. Now the current page is server B's webpage.

After whatever needs to be done on server B's webpage, server B uses HTTP to call back to server A.

Now, server A has received the request, and the controller needs to redirect the client back to webpage W. However, the HTTP request came from server B, not the client. I couldn't just tell the request to redirect to webpage W because the request didn't come from the client.

The HTTP request comes from server B, and server A catches it, but then how does server A know the original client (me) to redirect to webpage W?

In more vague terms, is there a way for my server to find the original client session after a redirect to another domain?

Comment: Redirect the client back to the original domain and the session cookie should still be there... it's really unclear what you're asking here.

Answer (score 0):

a real use-case may prove useful here however as I understand your question

Client (browser) loads webpage from your server.
Then the client makes another request to your server via ajax.

At some point you describe a redirect to server B.  It is unclear if this is done via a location header in the ajax response or if after receiving the ajax response javascript is used on the client to then redirect the page to server B.

I'm going to assume it is client side javascript beings you said that server A responds to the ajax request with OK (implying 200, not 302 or 301)

So if the client is now looking at server B, and server B (not the client) makes a request to server A then it is a totally new session, all you know is what is sent to you.  However you should reply to the request the same regardless of where it comes from.

for example, suppose you had an endpoint /foo .. the reply to /foo would be the same if it came from the client, or from server B .. you have no control over the client from server A.